# How to fix "Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

I have set up a ruby and ruby on rails environment on my Mac running Yosemite and am trying to work my way through a tutorial.  I am stopped from doing so immediately when I do the following in my bash terminal:

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.2.1@ learn-rails --create
Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): learn-rails.
```

I believe everything is set up correctly.  Here's what I get when I do the following:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

and:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.1

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.26.10 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ echo $PATH
/Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/jeff/.rbenv/shims:/Users/jeff/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/bin
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the link of the tutorial you followed?

Comment: Well, it's a kindle book on Amazon but I believe there may be a web version, too: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00QK2T1SY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no space between the `@` character and `learn-rails`. The extra space is causing RVM to misinterperet `learn-rails` as a version of Ruby to use. The line should read:

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.1@learn-rails --create
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you for that and never again will I copy and paste from kindle where coding is concerned! (It was correct in the book, without the space, but when copied and pasted, the space appeared.  Hour and hours on this...geeze!)